# Dealing with a minmaxer player - is this legal?

Tags: dnd-5e, racial-traits, proficiency

So, the main question is, can one create expertise through using proficiency and another proficiency?

Let me try and explain, A level 9 mind flayer savant player character would regularly roll +13 to perception rolls due to a skill that allowed skills to be int based instead of wis or cha (ignore the stat switching) and so the equation comes out like this: 5(int) + 4 (proficiency) +4 (race proficiency) = +13 to perception rolls and a passive perception of 23.

He claimed it was kosher for race proficiency and trained proficiency to stack, saying it was in the PHB. I can't find anything like that and the internet is stuck on teaching the difference between base proficiency vs expertise.

So in short: Is there a way to stack proficiency (from any source) or is that him misunderstanding (or just wrong)?

Comment: Mind Flayer PCs are not a published option in D&D 5e, nor are racial or trained proficiency really terms in 5e. Are you (or your player) using homebrew material or material or rules (references) from older editions of the game?

Comment: Also, while the self-censoring is appreciated, I removed that language and the unrelated rant about bugbears. Please remember to keep questions and answers focused and to be polite (even to/about yourself).

Comment: Actually, does the linked question answer your question? If not, please edit to clarify or tell us here in the comments if you are unsure.

Comment: But where are my manners, Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Reading the initial version of this question and the lack of understanding on proficiency I would be very cautious in your case because you are allowing home brew races without a full understanding of the rules and therefore balance implications behind them. Even bugbears while official are not intended for usual play, and mindflayer races I have seen are often overpowered. For example allowing all skills to be INT based is nuts and just ruins the game for any other character in my opinion.

Comment: I would add a second note, rather than the player being wrong or misunderstanding, please ensure they are not simply taking advantage of you.